# Плагин Wordpress, получение данных post

Tags: wordpress, post

Здравствуйте, делаю плагин для Wordpress и столкнулся с такой проблемой: необходимо получать данные от стороннего сервиса методом POST на какой-либо URL (указывается на стороннем сервисе). Как мне лучше реализовать прием этих данных на каком-либо URL и потом последующая передача в сам "обработчик" плагина.

В общем надо принять данные методом POST и потом их использовать в плагине.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то при переходе на указанный урл, должен выполняться скрипт, который соберет данные из массива $_POST (или потока php://input) и передаст их в метод Вашего плагина.

Например:

server_callback.php

```
include('path/to/Plugin.php');
$id = $_POST['client_id'];
$amount = $_POST['payment_amount'];
$signature = $_POST['signature'];
$plugin = new Plugin();
try {
    $plugin->process($id, $amount, $signature);
} catch (PluginException $e) {
    // обработка исключения, логирование ошибок
}
```

Прочитать про потоки ввода-вывода можно здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php

Вам нужно будет также так настроить роутинг на Вашем сайте, чтобы при запросе соответствующего URL, вызывался скрипт server_callback.php.
При этом вызов скрипта будет происходить в новом сеансе, поэтому не стоит использовать данные из массива $_SESSION, при этом, скорее всего (если не переназначать директивы в .htaccess), вызов Вашего скрипта пройдет через Front Controller WordPress, а значит будет работать внутри собранного WP окружения.